# phantom error "error parsing XML: unbound prefix"

Tags: xml, android, eclipse, syntax

The error "error parsing XML: unbound prefix" shows up on my main layout: main.xml when I first open Eclipse. To make the error go away, all I  have to do is make a modification to the file, then undo it, then hit save (have to make a change in order to be able to save file and thus trigger the new syntax check).

My environment is:

```
Fedora Eclipse Platform
Version: 3.4.2
Based on build id:  20090211-1700
```

My target is Android API level 5.

The first time I saw the error I spent a long time trying to track down "the problem" but later realized there isn't really a problem, it's just a phantom error.

Screenshot: http://i50.tinypic.com/2i89iee.jpg

Who should I report this to?

Comment: hmm i got the same problem from time to time. all i have to do is to make a full rebuild. i don't know if it is a android bug, an eclipse bug or even no bug at all but a feature :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a bug with the [ADT plugin for Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html). I'd first [check if it's already filed](http://b.android.com); if not, go ahead and [report it](http://b.android.com/new) at `b.android.com`.

Answer (score 2):

Once i build project with it and spent much time with this.
It may also be included in the .java files (you have added by accident) line:

```
import android.R
```

Now it thinks that we need this prefix:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Solve:
  Find and delete this line and re-build project:

```
// DELETE import android.R
```

Add your package Resources import:

```
import com.johnsmith.example
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and here is what I did.

- First go down to the problems tab and select the unbound prefix error
- Right click it and select delete.
- It will give you a warning  message just click OK and you should be
  good to go.

I **wouldn't recommend using this for all problems** just for the phantom errors that don't seem to be caused by anything.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Change the flipper id to vflipper

because android xml doesn't support capitol letter for declaring values